# How to create JSON output from a combined group of composite classes with Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am a Scala newbie, extending someone else's code. The code uses the Play framework's JSON libraries. I am accessing objects of class  `Future[Option[A]]` and `Future[Option[List[B]]`. The classes `A` and `B` each have their own JSON `writes` method, so each can return JSON as a response to a web request. I'm trying to combine these into a single JSON response that I can return as an HTTP response.

I thought creating a class which composes `A` and `B` into a single class would allow me to do this, something along these lines:

```
case class AAndB(a: Future[Option[A]], b: Future[Option[List[B]]])
object AAndB {
    implicit val implicitAAndBWrites = Json.writes[AAndB]
}
```

But that fails all over the place. A and B are both structured like this:

```
sealed trait A extends SuperClass {
    val a1: String = "identifier"
}

case class SubA(a2: ClassA2) extends A {
    override val a1: String = "sub identifier"
}

object SubA {
    val writes = Writes[SubA] { aa =>
        Json.obj(
            "a1" -> aa.a1
            "a2" -> aa.a2
        )
    }
}
```

Since `B` is accessed as a List, the expected output would be along these lines:

```
{  
   "a":{  
      "a1":"val1",
      "a2":"val2"
   },
   "b":[  
      {  
         "b1":"val 3",
         "b2":"val 4"
      },
      {  
         "b1":"val 5",
         "b2":"val 6"
      },
      {  
         "b1":"val 7",
         "b2":"val 8"
      }
   ]
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share the json structure of A and B. and the sample final json structure joining A and B?

Comment: It's doubtful to have a `Future` as `case class` property

Answer (score 1):

As @cchantep mentioned in the comments on your question, having `Future`s as part of a `case class` declaration is highly unusual - case classes are great for encapsulating immutable domain objects (i.e that don't change over time) but as soon as you involve a `Future[T]` you potentially have multiple outcomes:

- The `Future` hasn't completed yet
- The `Future` failed
- The `Future` completed successfully, and contains a `T` instance

You don't want to tangle up this temporal stuff with the act of converting to JSON. For this reason you should model your wrapper class with the `Future`s removed:

```
case class AAndB(a: Option[A], b: Option[List[B]])
object AAndB {
  implicit val implicitAAndBWrites = Json.writes[AAndB]
}
```

and instead use Scala/Play's very concise handling of them in your `Controller` class to access the contents of each. In the below example, assume the existence of injected service classes as follows:

```
class AService {
  def findA(id:Int):Future[Option[A]] = ...
}

class BListService {
  def findBs(id:Int):Option[Future[List[B]]] = ...
}
```

Here's what our controller method might look like:

```
def showCombinedJson(id:Int) = Action.async {

  val fMaybeA = aService.findA(id)
  val fMaybeBs = bService.findBs(id)

  for {
    maybeA <- fMaybeA
    maybeBs <- fMaybeBs
  } yield {
    Ok(Json.toJson(AAndB(maybeA, maybeBs)))
  }
}
```

So here we launch both the A- and B-queries in parallel (we have to do this *outside* the `for`-comprehension to achieve this parallelism). The `yield` block of the `for`-comprehension will be executed *only* if/when both the `Future`s complete successfully - at which point it is safe to access the contents within. Then it's a simple matter of building an instance of the wrapper class, converting to JSON and returning an `Ok` result to Play.

Note that the result of the `yield` block *will itself* be inside a `Future` (in this case it's a `Future[Result]`) so we use Play's `Action.async` Action builder to handle this - letting Play deal with all of the actual waiting-for-things-to-happen.